# Removing zeros from an array and resizing the array to the new amount of elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am having another problem with manipulating data in a C++ array. I now want to decimate the array by removing all the zeros from it.

So for example say before I had `array[4] = {1,2,0,0,4}` It would become `array[3] = {1,2,4}`.

I know that I will need to use a for loop to iterate through the array storing the main data and that I will most likely need to initialize a new array to store the decimated data but I am not quite sure how to go about it.

Comment: The size of an array is part of its type, and an object's type cannot be modified. Therefore arrays can never be resized. You can create a new array of a different size and copy elements over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to resize array's why not simply use std::vector.  The example does it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isZero (int i) 
{
    return i == 0;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> myarray;

    myarray.push_back( 0 );
    myarray.push_back( 1 );
    myarray.push_back( 0 );
    myarray.push_back( 3 );
    myarray.push_back( 9 );

    std::vector<int>::iterator newIter = std::remove_if( myarray.begin() , myarray.end() , isZero);
    myarray.resize( newIter -  myarray.begin() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think if he doesn't even know how to write a for loop it may be a bit over the top to mix in vectors :)

Comment: That is why I didn't mix lambdas :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the function isZero you called there. Could you explain to me what it is doing and how this bit of code works? At the moment, I am not sure how to implement this bit of code to remove the zeros out of my array.

Comment: @user1452373 std::remove_if removes all elements that match a criteria. The criteria is the IsZero function that you want.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar Why use `remove_if` if `remove` works equally well?

Comment: `resize` is an operation that costs O(n). It might not be a good idea to use it. Especially in C++11, where you have `shrink_to_fit` that costs O(1).

Comment: can you point me to some documenation where shrink_to_fit is O(1)

Answer (score 16):

You cannot resize a plain array, since it is statically allocated. Thus, it is probably better to use a [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) from the standard library (STL). In such a way you would not need to create a new array. Actually, unless there is a strong reason, it is typically better to use `std::vector` or `std::array` (in C++11) than plain C-like arrays.

By using `vector`, you can do something like:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,0,0,4};
v.erase(
    std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 0),
    v.end());
```

After erasing the zero elements, the vector still has capacity 5, though (of course `v.size()` would return 3, as expected). If you can use C++11 then you can go a little bit further:

```
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

The call to `shrink_to_fit` reduces the vector's capacity to accommodate it to the actual number of elements in it (3 in the example). That could lead to memory savings (especially if there are many elements in the vector).

Comment: strictly speaking, the OP requires an array and not std::vector.

Comment: I thought zeros will be moved to the end... how will shrink to fit help ?

Comment: You can "resize" an array using `realloc`. But it only makes it bigger.

Comment: @0A0D But not a static array like the OP is asking for. `realloc` works for _dynamic_ arrays previously allocated with `malloc` (or similar).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the content of the array, you cannot know how many
values will be non-zero, so your memory must be dynamically
allocated. Use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::copy_if(begin(array), end(array), std::back_inserter(v),
             [](int x) { return x != 0; });
```

If you would start with a `vector` to begin with, you could manipulate the data in-place with erase-remove.

```
v.erase(std::remove(begin(v), end(v), 0), end(v));
```

If you really want to do it the hard way:

```
// count
auto non_zero_count = std::count_if(begin(array), end(array), 
                                    [](int x) { return x != 0;});
// allocate
int* new_array{new int[x]};
std::copy_if(begin(array), end(array), new_array,
             [](int x) { return x != 0; });
```

There is really no solution to arrive at fixed size array here, unless you know all your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array and you want to remove the 0 value in the array and resize it.

```
int toResize[] = {4,3,2,0,8,7,9,0,5,4,7,0}; //12 elements
vector<int>resized;
vector<int>::iterator it;
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
int check = toResize[i];
    if(check!=0){
     resized.push_back(check);
    }
}

for ( it=resized.begin() ; it < resized.end(); it++ )
cout << " " << *it;
```

Feel free to mark the question answered if you are satisfied.